# How do you make Visual Studio Code veracode greenlight scan ignore xml or yaml files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, veracode

I have veracode extension installed in VS Code. When I do greenlight scan of a subdir that has an xml or yaml file the scan halts and says it can't scan these files. How can I make it ignore these files and move on without stopping?

Comment: Good practice, in general, is to keep source code in separate directories from supporting files. Like that you can run the scan on particular directories. I know that is not a direct answer to your question. I used Github actions to scan my projects and I had to separate like that the source code from .ymls, .xmls etc or specify one by one the source files to pack and send for a scan to avoid packing the supporting ones.